# Easy table transpose in hive

Tags: sql, hive, transpose

I need to transpose my table. 
Now i have that type of table:

```
Atr_1|Atr_2
 A   | 1
 A   | 2
```

But i want to get the next result

```
Atr_1|Atr_2|Atr_3
 A   | 1   |  2
```

How should i transpose my table for achieving this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case statements with `min()` or `max()` aggregation:

```
select Atr_1,
       max(case when Atr_2=1 then 1 end ) Attr_2,
       max(case when Atr_2=2 then 2 end ) Attr_3
  from table t
 group by Atr_1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two values, `min()` and `max()` do what you want:

```
select atr_1, min(atr_2) as atr_2, max(atr_3) as atr_3
from t
group by atr_1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want aggregation :

```
SELECT atr_1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQ = 1 THEN atr_2 END) as atr_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQ = 2 THEN atr_2 END) as atr_3
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY atr_1 ORDER BY atr_2) AS SEQ
      FROM table t
     ) t
GROUP BY atr_1;
```