# how to create pivot/transpose table in hive

Tags: hive

select st_date,st_symbol,st_adjclose from table;

```
2019-02-19  MSFT    107.71
2019-02-20  MSFT    107.15
2019-03-01  AAPL    174.97
2019-01-02  AAPL    157.25
2019-01-08  AMZN    1656.58
2019-01-07  AMZN    1629.51
2019-01-03  GOOGL   1025.47
2019-01-04  GOOGL   1078.07


date            MSFT      AAPL     AMZN      GOOGL   

2019-02-19      107.71    141.58   141.58    141.58
2019-02-20      107.71    157.25   157.25    157.25
2019-02-22      110.97    157.25   157.25    157.25
```

Comment: Why in the result AAPL = 141.58 for 2019-02-19 date? And why GOOGL  = 141.58 ? Bother to describe your logic

Comment: i made that for example. need table like that.

Comment: Should it be sum or max() or what. Figures are confusing completely.

Comment: General approach is like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770081/2700344 or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535243/2700344. You should know values in advance, Hive does not support dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know in advance which stock symbols you want in your query, then you can do it using `MAP` :

```
SELECT   st_date, 
         SUM(t.value_map['MSFT'])  AS MSFT, 
         SUM(t.value_map['AAPL'])  AS AAPL, 
         SUM(t.value_map['AMZN'])  AS AMZN, 
         SUM(t.value_map['GOOGL']) AS GOOGL 
FROM     ( 
                SELECT st_date, 
                       map(st_symbol,st_adjclose) AS value_map 
                FROM   ( 
                              SELECT st_date, 
                                     st_symbol, 
                                     st_adjclose 
                              FROM   TABLE ) x ) t 
GROUP BY st_date;
```

Let me know if it works